# Java: Extending class with generics

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

How would I extend this class

```
 public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E>
```

I am trying to create AVL tree class which extends BST.

I have

```
 public class AVL extends BST<E>
```

but i'm getting error cannot find symbol for the E. I have tried

```
public class AVL<E extends BST<E>>
```

and receive error as well E1 extends BST but E2 extends Comparable.

Comment: Look at your first class. How is that declared? How does what you are doing compare to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
 public class AVL<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BST<E>
```

Why?

You need to satisfy generic constraint of parameter `E` of  `BST` class - `<E extends Comparable<E>>` and as you can see in the definition above, you are meeting that requirement.

Comment: Explanation would be nice.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Was just writing it :)